# How to wrap object in array in java?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I'm making a code to send data to the payment gateway. I am a beginner in using java. I'm having a bit of trouble working with objects in an array in the item_details parameter. I've made the code as below.

```
public KeyValuePair<String, String> requestSnapToken(String orderNo, 
        BigDecimal grossAmount, int paymentMethodId,
        String firstName,
        String email, 
        List<FormCartLine> itemDetails 
        ) {
    return FAILSAFE_EXECUTOR.get(() -> {
        String midtransOrderId = orderNo;
        Builder<String, Object> custDetailBuilder = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>()
            .put("first_name", firstName)
            .put("last_name", "");
        Builder<String, Object> itemDetailsBuilder = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>();

        for (int i = 0; i < itemDetails.size(); i++) { 
            FormCartLine line = itemDetails.get(i); 
            int row = i + 1;  
            itemDetailsBuilder.put($("id%s", row), line.getProductId()) 
                .put($("price%s", row), line.getUnitPricePreTax()) 
                .put($("quantity%s", row), line.getQty()) 
                .put($("name%s", row), line.getName()) 
                .put($("brand%s", row), line.getBrandName()) 
                .put($("category%s", row), line.getCategoryName()); 
        } 
    
        Builder<String, Object> payloadBuilder = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>()
            .put("transaction_details", new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>()
                    .put("order_id", midtransOrderId)
                    .put("gross_amount", String.valueOf(grossAmount.longValue()))
                    .build())
            .put("item_details", itemDetailsBuilder.build())
    });
}
```

I tried to debug from the code that I made, the payload looks like this. This is not what I wanted..

```
  "transaction_details" : {
    "order_id" : "S415",
    "gross_amount" : "194547"
  },
  "item_details" : {
    "id1" : "001",
    "price1" : 200,
    "quantity1" : 1,
    "name1" : "Dummy 1",
    "brand1" : "Dummy",
    "category1" : "Dummies",
    "id2" : "002",
    "price2" : 300,
    "quantity2" : 1,
    "name2" : "Dummy 2",
    "brand2" : "Dummy",
    "category2" : "Dummies"
  },
```

what i want is like below. How do I implement it in java?

```
  "transaction_details" : {
    "order_id" : "S415",
    "gross_amount" : "194547"
  },
  "item_details" : [{
    "id" : "001",
    "price" : 200,
    "quantity" : 1,
    "name" : "Dummy 1",
    "brand" : "Dummy",
    "category" : "Dummies"
  },
  {

    "id" : "002",
    "price" : 300,
    "quantity" : 1,
    "name" : "Dummy 2",
    "brand" : "Dummy",
    "category" : "Dummies"
  }
]
```

Comment: `$(…)` is not valid Java syntax (at least none I'm aware of)

Comment: @knittl Well, that *could* be just a method. The `$` is also a valid Java identifier character, just like all alphanumerics. So while it looks strange, it is just a normal method. See [JLS § 3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

Comment: this is plain JSON, why not just use something like GSON to build these for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build separate maps for each of your objects and put those maps into a list. Immutability is probably not required, so I'll simplify by using an `ArrayList`:

```
final List<Map<String, Object>> itemDetailsList = new ArrayList<>(itemDetails.size());
for (final FormCartLine line : itemDetails) {
    itemDetailsList.add(Map.ofEntries(
            Map.entry("id", line.getProductId()),
            Map.entry("price", line.getUnitPricePreTax()),
            // etc.
    ));
}

// ...

Builder<String, Object> payloadBuilder = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>()
    // .put(...)
    .put("item_details", itemDetailsList)
```

Note that the map returned by `Map.ofEntries` cannot hold null values, so if that's a requirement, you need to switch to a `HashMap<String, Object>` or another map type with support for null values.

Of course, you can use an `ImmutableMap.Builder` too if you prefer or the loop could be converted to use the Java stream API.